# Evaluate $\int _0 ^1 \frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{(e^{ax}+1)(e^{bx}+1)} \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration

Evaluate $$\int _0 ^1 \frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{(e^{ax}+1)(e^{bx}+1)} \mathrm{d}x$$ where $a$ and $b$ are constant. I attempt to factor the fraction but then have no ideas where to go. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: $(1/r)-(1/s)=(s-r)/rs$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int _0 ^1 \frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{(e^{ax}+1)(e^{bx}+1)} \mathrm{d}x$$

= $$\int _0 ^1 \frac{(e^{ax}+1) -(e^{bx}+1)}{(e^{ax}+1)(e^{bx}+1)} \mathrm{d}x$$

= $$\int _0 ^1 \frac{1}{(e^{bx}+1)} \mathrm{d}x$$ + $$\int _0 ^1 \frac{1}{(e^{ax}+1)} \mathrm{d}x$$

now for first integral substitute  $(e^{bx}+1)$=u and for second integral substitute $(e^{ax}+1)$=v

now

= $$\int _2 ^{1+e^b}\frac{1}{b(u-1))}\mathrm{d}u$$ +$$\int _2 ^{1+e^a}\frac{1}{a(v-1))}\mathrm{d}v$$

i will leave it there hope you can manage rest if not ask i will type the rest

Comment: I would have liked to see whether OP could have come up with this, using the hint in the comments. It would have been a learning experience.

Comment: Instead we have an example of the "shopping at MSE experience". (@Jam: the upper bounds in the last integrals are incorrect.)

Comment: @Did thanks for the man i should have paid more attention and i have edited thanks

Comment: @GerryMyerson first of all i always don't read comments because there is too much bickering so i don't pay attention second if you had a left an answer saying as a hint and write what you have written in comments i wouldn't have bothered writing an answer.  I for one feel there are too many opinions on how to write answer and when to write answer on MSE by a handful of users. I have no time for time paying attention to those as my time is better utilised on trying to help another student.

Comment: Actually, I did figure out the partial fractions at first. The substitution is a little trickier. Do the substitution as @Jan suggested and then apply partial fraction again, I got the result $log \frac{e+1}{2}(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b})$. Many thanks to both you guys. I really enjoy the learning experience here.

Comment: We're all trying to help students here, Jam, it's just a question of whether it's more helpful in the long run to give 90% of the answer, or to give 10% and encourage the student to work out the rest.